# How does sensitive information leak assist in exploit development?

Tags: exploit

According to [this bug report](http://secunia.com/advisories/52340/), the first vulnerability can leak sensitive information.

But since it doesn't mention what information to leak, I guess it would be the stack? And how could this help in exploit development?

Comment: Very nice question. I recommend having a look at [this article about a similar subject](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/ERR01-J.+Do+not+allow+exceptions+to+expose+sensitive+information). It probably doesn't contain an exact answer, but it approaches your question with some good information.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, that kind of leak (reading a string which was not NULL-terminated) results in reading what happens to reside in RAM just after the string. Then this depends on where the string is. If the string is stack-allocated, then this discloses part of the stack (since stacks "grow down", this will explore local variables of callers of the current function). If the string is heap-allocated, then the reading will overflow in adjacent blocks, which can be about anything, depending on all previous allocations since last boot, so this is rather unpredictable.

There are some high-value targets in the kernel (e.g. encryption keys for in-kernel cryptographic operations). These targets can be in local variables, block-allocated objects... it really depends on the context. Simply reading the local stack can help a lot in fine tuning a buffer overflow exploit (a non-tuned buffer overflow leads to a crash, a tuned buffer overflow can lead to arbitrary code execution).

Most peeks at the kernel memory won't reveal anything of value, because 99.9% (at least) of memory used by some code (be it the kernel or some application) is not *really* confidential and could be revealed with no ill effect. However, it is very hard to precisely locate the remaining 0.1%: guaranteeing that a given piece of information is *not* sensitive is nigh infeasible in the general case. So it is safest to consider such information leak vulnerabilities as "potentially serious", and fix them.

Answer (score 1):

In the kernel land,  the ability to read memory addresses can undermine ASLR.  Randomization is about secrets,  and if you can read these secrets then ASLR isn't very helpful.

A simple example in the web app world is using error information disclosure to obtain a full path.  With the full path you could use directory traversal to access the web root,  or use mysql's `into outfile` or `load_file()` to access files in the web root.